# Can't delete C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent

Tags: windows-7

Right-clicking the folder (the icon looks different) has no option to delete. Also `del C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent*.* /Q` gives no error, but the file is still there. I'm trying to delete it because according to the logs it's preventing this PC from upgrading to Windows 10.

Comment: Boot from a linux boot disk and delete the file that way.

Comment: true, I am doing it via TeamViewer, and there is no way someone at the location can do this

Comment: There are delete utilities out there if this is an option for you.

Comment: shouldn't it be `...ecent\*.*` ?

Comment: I tried both ways, same result sadly